# GeoServer: CQL_Filter working with operator '=' but not with operator 'IN'

Tags: geoserver

WMS 1:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mtm/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=copper_cable&tiled=true&tilesorigin=-20037508.34%2C-20037508.34&viewparams=import_job_code%3Anull&cql_filter=id%20%3D%274ABC-01-12-ABC-108%27&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=2858&HEIGHT=778&BBOX=17003975.290642627%2C-3209930.007007534%2C17005681.98616457%2C-3209465.4131950526

WMS 2:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mtm/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng8&TRANSPARENT=true&layers=copper_cable&tiled=true&tilesorigin=-20037508.34%2C-20037508.34&viewparams=import_job_code%3Anull&cql_filter=id%20IN(%274ABC-01-12-ABC-108%27)&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=2858&HEIGHT=778&BBOX=17003975.290642627%2C-3209930.007007534%2C17005681.98616457%2C-3209465.4131950526

In WMS 1 I am using CQL_Filer has operator '=' and is working fine

In WMS 2 I am using CQL_Filter has operator "IN" and is not workig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query partly URL-decoded for clarity: `cql_filter=id IN('4ABC-01-12-ABC-108')`).

The IN part is using correct syntax and you can test that it works with this query:

[https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&propertyname=STATE_NAME&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME IN ('Illinois')](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&propertyname=STATE_NAME&CQL_FILTER=STATE_NAME%20IN%20(%27Illinois%27))

It may be that your problem is connected to making a query by attribute "id". As documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html feature id's are used in a specific way in CQL_FILTER. Try to write the filter without specifying any attribute

```
cql_filter=IN('4ABC-01-12-ABC-108')
```

If this does not work and if you do not get more feedback from gis.stackexchange I suggest to write a mail to the geoserver-users mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. As you mentioned the issue is because of "id".But cql_filter=IN('4ABC-01-12-ABC-108') is not working .

Comment: will follow your suggestion.